# How to mapping JSON Object with VueJS and AXIOS

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

How to mapping the JSON Object with the variable? I am not sure that my coding is correct or not.
I just begin study in Vuejs.
Please see my coding I want to map jSON data to the 'country' variable.

```js
  var appZone = new Vue({
 el: '#el',
 data() {
  return {
    country:  [],
    shoppingItems: [
   {name: 'apple', price: '10'},
   {name: 'orange', price: '12'}
    ]
  }
 },
 mounted() {
  axios.get('/wp-json/tour-api/v1/search/11361')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
      this.country = response.json();
   
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
   }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="el">
<ul>
        <li v-for="item in country">
          {{ item.country_id }}  -  {{ item.title }}
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image: Here is my JSON]

Here is my JSON data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the mounted function to

```
mounted() {
    var self = this
    axios.get('/wp-json/tour-api/v1/search/11361')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      self.country = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

self is being used to maintain a reference to the original this even as the context is changing. It's a technique often used in event handlers (especially in closures).

Comment: did you mean 'var self = this' ?

Comment: It should be response.data instead of response.json()